# REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Duration]: [Duration]

Tags: apex

I am passing a datetime field value from screen flow to apex controller and creating an Event. On inserting i am getting an error :

```
REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Duration]: [Duration]
```

The value which i am receiving from flow is `meetingtime = 2021-07-18 09:40:00` of type Datetime

Creating Event

```
Event e = new Event();
e.StartDateTime = meetingtime
```

Comment: You are probably missing Duration field on Event.

Comment: How to add tht one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Duration field as follows. Probably you would like to pass the Event Duration from the flow or set some default duration as 123 for example.

```
Event e = new Event();
e.StartDateTime = meetingtime;
e.Duration = 123;
```

Comment: I m not sure why this question is off topic and given 3 negative points. I wrote that i am inserting Event with the details i gave above . I dont know for creating records what else i would have written .. whoever has marked it as off topic please answer...